# get generated xml from internet into delphi app

Tags: xml, delphi, indy, delphi-xe6

im working in Delphi XE6 and need to download xml data that is generated by php script on server. I did try with Indy IdHTTP.Get but it doesn't download anything... When i try open same link in browser or in TWebBrowser it shows generated xml data, but when i try to directly pull it with IdHTTP Get, nothing is downloaded, like there is no generated data...

```
Memo1.Lines.Add := idHTTP.Get(url);
```

Gives empty memo1.

Any tips or examples how to first execute php script on some server that will generate data, and pull down that result?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows' URLDownloadToFile function?

Comment: Get Wireshark (or some other purpose-built traffic sniffer). Compare what a browser sends on a good request with what your program sends on a bad request.

Comment: The code you included won't even compile, as `Memo1.Lines.Add` is a function, not a property, and therefore you can't assign to it using `:=`. Please do not include made-up code and expect us to be able to figure out why it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   dow: TIdHTTP;
   xmlDoc: TXMLDocument;
   xmlStrem: TMemoryStream;
begin
   dow := nil;
   xmlDoc := nil;
   xmlStrem := nil;
   try
      try
         dow := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
         dow.HandleRedirects := True;
         xmlStrem := TMemoryStream.Create();
         dow.Get('http://url.com/path/', xmlStrem);
         xmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(Self);
         xmlDoc.LoadFromStream(xmlStrem);
         ShowMessage(xmlDoc.XML.Text);
      except
         on E: Exception do
         begin
            raise;
         end;
      end;
   finally
      if Assigned(dow) then FreeAndNil(dow);
      if Assigned(xmlDoc) then FreeAndNil(xmlDoc);
      if Assigned(xmlStrem) then FreeAndNil(xmlStrem);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't use a `TStringStream`, especially in Delphi 2009+. It requires an `TEncoding` in the constructor, and if the encoding specified does not match the XML enoding, you can lose data. Use a `TMemoryStream` instead.

Comment: The default encoding used by `TStringStream` is not UTF-8, but the default XML charset is UTF-8.

Comment: yes, I agree with what you said, I changed my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to set `xmlStream.Position` back to 0 before calling `loadFromStream()`.

Comment: yes, if i use xmlStrem later, but is only an intermediate between TIdHTTP and TXMLDocument, xmlStrem will be freed, but if i will use xmlStream later, i have to use xmlStrem.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

Comment: You usually have to seek back to 0 every time.  The only times you don't need to are if you call `xmlStream.SaveToFile()` (saves the entire stream regardless of `Position`), or if you access `xmlStream.Memory` directly.

Comment: I know its a little late, but why do you set dow, xmlDoc and xmlStrem to nil at the beginning?

Comment: @KevinBöhmer I was not sure if the object would be initialized with nil, so for sure, I initialized the object with nil, so I could use the following code snippet "if Assigned (dow) then FreeAndNil (dow);" in the finally block

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `UnicodeString`, so `TIdHTTP` will receive the raw XML data and decode it to UTF-16 using the XML's specified charset. If there is a problem determining that charset and/or decoding the data, a blank string may be returned without an exception being raised.

XML is a binary format, subject to its charset.  So you really should be downloading the XML as binary, such as with a `TMemoryStream`, and then passing that as-is to your XML parser for processing.  Let it deal with the XML's charset, don't let Indy handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying and searching, i did change

*UserAgent* instead of *Mozilla/3.0* into *Mozilla/5.0*

and it works now. And yes, 
`xmlStream.Position := 0;`

Thnx for help!